# Print in a previous line after that line

Tags: php

I want to print between the blocks, but obviously it prints after the blocks. Is there any way to do that wiht only PHP?

```
<?php

  echo 'Block 1 <br>';

  function printHere() {

    echo 'printed <br>';

  }

  echo 'Block 2 <br>';

  printHere();
```

The function printHere must be after the Block 2, because I don't know if I have to print that line until after the block 2.

The blocks are a representation of code blocks that must be in that position.

I don't know if it's possible because I've to modify an `echo` previously printed.

Comment: It prints after the blocks because that's where you've told it to print - what did you think would happen?

Comment: write the texts to strings first, then output the strings in the order you want

Comment: @Karsten Koop I don't know if I have to print that line after the Block 2.

Comment: @kerbholz Block 2 actually it's a code block which evaluates if printHere must be called.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

echo 'Block 1 <br>';
function printHere() {
    echo 'printed <br>';
}

printHere();

echo 'Block 2 <br>';
```

**Edit: Simple example**

```
<?php

$block1 = 'Block 1 <br>';
$block2 = 'Block 2<br>';

function printHere() {
    return 'printed <br>';
}

$block1 .= printHere();

echo $block1;
echo $block2;
```

Comment: The function printHere must be after the Block 2.

Comment: Thanks @MPAvance but in this particulare case I can't move the statements of position.